# Email Notifications/Alerts from Builds in TFS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, tfs-alerts

I am having problems getting the team alerts to work in TFS 2010.

Under "Team > Project Alerts", I have checked the box to send both myself and a colleague an email upon a completed build.  I know I have entered the correct email addresses, correct syntax as far as separating the emails, yet neither I nor my colleague receive any emails when the build is complete.

So far, I haven't found anything online regarding troubleshooting this issue.  I was wondering if anyone has encountered the same problem or otherwise knows of a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually this boils down to a configuration problem within the TFS setup.

If you have access to the tfs server, run the TFS Administration Console.

If you click on TFS / Application Tier on the left, you'll see the Application Tier settings come up.  Scroll down to the Email Alert Settings.

Make sure it's enabled and has the correct configuration for sending messages.

Comment: In the TFS Administration Console I cannot see anywhere that says "Application Tier" I currently have my local machine set up as the build agent and that is the only settings I am able to see

Comment: @AmbiguousX: You need to do this from the TFS server itself, not the local box.